# remove spaces in the columns in ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have columns that contain empty spaces with the data:
example:| fish |
how can I update the column so my result will be : |Fish| ?
in oracle I can trim the column:

```
update Example set column1 = trim(column1)
```

I google it and i notice that ASE doesnt supoort trim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use combine of [rtrim](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks201.htm) and [ltrim](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks172.htm)

```
update Example set column1 = rtrim(ltrim(column1))
```

or [str_replace](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks213.htm)

```
update Example set column1 = str_replace(column1,' ','')
```

Comment: with str_replace(column1,' ','') don´t work for me. But, str_replace(column1, ' ', null), work fine for me.

Comment: @jonatanes Probably it depends on ASE's version. Probably you have got newer version than I had got 4 (sic!) years ago! The answer is accepted so it was good for the OP's ASE's version. Do you think downvoting is good for this situation?

Answer (score 11):

I found that str_replace(column1, ' ', '') does not actually replace the spaces.

Switching the '' for null works:

```
create table Example (column1 varchar(15))
insert into Example (column1) values ('| fish |')
select * from Example
-- produces "| fish |"

update Example set column1 = str_replace(column1, ' ', null)
select * from Example
-- produces "|fish|"

drop table Example
```

Comment: It is so strange that trying to remove a string from text with '' as the replacement string doesn't work.  Thanks for pointing out that null will work.